# What if the Riemann Hypothesis were false?

Tags: nt.number-theory, big-list, riemann-hypothesis

There are lots of known and interesting consequences of the Riemann Hypothesis being true. Are there any known and interesting consequences of the Riemann Hypothesis being false?

Comment: If it were false, a consequence would be that the distribution of the primes would have be to be more interesting than currently (generally) believed. This is a bit of a meta answer. But it would be highly interesting if it were false. In that sense RH true is the more "boring" case.

Comment: In the early 20th century, the proof that the class number of imaginary quadratic fields ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ for squarefree $d > 0$ tends to $\infty$ as $d \rightarrow \infty$ was based on a two-part argument:  Landau showed that it follows from the assumption that GRH is true for the $L$-functions of all imaginary quadratic Dirichlet characters, and then Heilbronn showed that it follows from the assumption that GRH is false for the $L$-function of some imaginary quadratic Dirichlet character. See Ireland and Rosen's number theory book, p. 359.

Comment: Before the work of Heilbronn, Mordell had shown that if infinitely many imaginary quadratic fields have the same class number (any common value) then RH for the Riemann zeta-function is true. Thus if RH is false, any positive integer can be the class number of finitely many imaginary quadratic fields.

Comment: About 10,000 published papers would be rendered vacuous.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let's not throw the baby out with the bath water!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

An explicit zero $\rho$ for $\zeta(s)$, off the critical line, would give an explicit lower bound on the class number $h(-d)$ for $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$, for a range of $-d$ in terms of $\text{Im}(\rho)$.  This is the 'Deuring-Heilbronn phenomenon,' with results due to these two and others beginning in the 1930's.  For an elementary account, see
http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0713

Comment: Such results "for a range of $d$" already exist, in terms of zeros which are closer than average (see Stark's thesis, or Montgomery/Weinberger I think though they use low-zeros of Dirichlet $L$-functions, same principle). So does this really have anything to do with RH failing per se? https://eudml.org/doc/205246‎
 http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55959/importance-of-large-gaps-between-zeros-of-zeta-function

Comment: @v08ltu:Yes, I have Stark's thesis in front of me.  Chapter 2 is the contrapositive, for class number 1.  A 10th such discriminant $-p$ would imply the Riemann Hypothesis up to height $\sqrt{p}/2$.  My answer above does say 'and others.'